# Getting load average as variables

Tags: linux

I'm setting up a logging script with Ruby and am having some difficulties with getting the load averages as a variable.  I'm using:

```
uptime | awk '{print $10}'
```

to get the current 1 minute time stamp, but I'm having trouble getting it without a trailing comma.  I could edit the string later, but that seems less efficient.  Is there an edit that will simply remove the `,` from the return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
cut -f 1 -d " " /proc/loadavg
```

The `uptime` command reads `/proc/loadavg` and then adds the commas.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, it also works through `/proc/loadavg`, but the usage is a little more idiomatic, so I thought I'd mention [the sys-cpu Gem](https://github.com/djberg96/sys-cpu) (which existed even in 2013 :)) as well:

```sh
gem install sys-cpu
```

```rb
require 'sys-cpu'
puts Sys::CPU.load_avg
```

... which will give you a nice array: `[0.72, 1.14, 1.11]`.